# Shortest path in directed graph with cycles of negative length

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Is there an algorithm for finding the shortest path in a directed graph which includes cycles of negative length? The constraint is that each node can only be visited once, so the solution exists.

I'm aware of the [Bellman-Ford](http://www.programming-algorithms.net/article/47389/Bellman-Ford-algorithm) algorithm, but it fails when negative cycles are present. It's also clear that traversing negative cycles forever makes the problem ill-defined, so I'm constraining the path to visit each node at most once.

Is there such an algorithm? And is there an off-the-shelf implementation I can use?

---EDIT---

As requested below, here's the actual application:

Given an input image containing handwriting, I can estimate probabilities of stroke directions at each pixel:
[image]

Then, I can put the pixels into a graph, and find the path of the pen:
[image]

See how the "l" is missed out? If I can set the adjacent weights to be negative, the optimal path will traverse all letters. But negative weights create negative cycles.

Comment: `And is there an off-the-shelf implementation I can use?` - most probably but it depends on the language you are working on. Python should have one of those off the shelf.

Comment: There is probably a better explanation but here is a counter-example where there is no efficient solution: Assume all link cost are negative. Then your problem boils down to [finding the longest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) (collecting as many negative cost as possible) which is NP-hard.

Comment: @SomeDude I'm language agnostic, python is fine. But what's the algorithm?

Comment: @SaiBot NP-hard problems can still have decent solutions for average-case complexity, and my graphs aren't fully connected. Is there an algorithm you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the Bellman-Ford algorithm fails in this case. You can refer section 2 of [this resource](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~goddyn/Courses/800/Resources/GraphMisc/short_path.pdf). It discusses the problem for an undirected graph and works based on Edmonds' Minimum Weight Perfect Matching Algorithm. In fact, you might be interested in [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/76578/finding-shortest-paths-in-undirected-graphs-with-possibly-negative-edge-weights), which is very similar to yours.

When the graph is a directed one, then as @SaiBot pointed out, the problem reduces to an NP Hard problem, and there is no efficient solution possible.

Comment: Interesting. So is this the "Hamilton Path Problem"?

Comment: Not exactly, but they are related in the sense that the Hamilton Path Problem can be reduced to the longest path problem. You might be interested in [this wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#NP-hardness)